# Append np.newaxis as needed

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I want to slice an array so that I can use it to perform an operation with another array of arbitrary dimension. In other words, I am doing the following:

```
A = np.random.rand(5)
B = np.random.rand(5,2,3,4)
slicer = [slice(None)] + [None]*(len(B.shape)-1)
result = B*A[slicer]
```

Is there some syntax that I can use so that I do not have to construct `slicer`?

Comment: Reshape could be one option : `B*A.reshape(A.shape + (1,)*(B.ndim-1))`, though essentially the same.

Comment: Your code reminds me of what `expand_dims` does internally,except that only adds 1 axis.  The broadcasting default is to expand in the other direction.  Wraping this action in your own function is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case you can use `np.einsum` with an ellipsis.

```
result2 = np.einsum('i,i...->i...', A, B)

np.allclose(result, result2)

Out[232]: True
```

Although, as @hpaulj points out this only works for multiplication (or division if you use `1/B`).

Since broadcasting works from the other end normally, you can use `np.transpose` twice get the axes in the right order.

```
result3 = np.transpose(np.transpose(B) * A)
```

But that's also not a general case

Comment: Nice but it is limited to multiplication.